# RESTfull APIs for write in datapoint and datasource

Tags: scadalts

I'm following the development of ScadaLTS, mainly an implementation of the RESTfull API. I would like to know, does a development team will implement as RESTfull APIs for write in datapoint and datasource?

Congratulations to ScadaLTS team for the beautiful development work.

Best regards

Jeferson